# Comparing adjacent values, deleting like pairs and comparing new list

Tags: python, list, compare

a = [1N, 1S, 1S, 2E, 2W, 1N, 2W]
Say I have a list like so. Is there a way to compare in a way that it will do the following.

```
Pseudo code: Iterate over list [1N, 1S, 1S, 2E, 2W, 1N, 2W], 1==1, delete those values. Iterate over
new list [1S, 2E, 2W, 1N, 2W], 1!=2, move on, 2==2 delete those values. Iterate
over new list [1S, 1N, 2W], 1==1, delete those values. Answer = 2W
```

What I have so far.

```
def dirReduc(arr):
    templist = []
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        a = arr[i - 1]
        b = arr[i]
        if a == b:
            templist = (arr[b:])
    (templist)
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
print(dirReduc(a)
```

Test case produces correct values, but I need to run tho loop until i only get two. Thats where i'm stuck

Comment: Try to write code (and the problems you have) so that we can help you.

Comment: Be careful! You are missing the `return` at the end of the` dirReduc` function (it should be something like 'return templist'). Without the function return `None`. Also it is necessary to close a `)` in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

If you can understand the problem, you only need a while to iterate as needed.

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
finished = False
while not finished:    # Iterate until finished = True
    finished = True    # That only happens when no repeated elements are found
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i] == a[i+1]:
            a.pop(i)   # When removing the element i from a,
            a.pop(i)   # now the i + 1 is in the place of i
            print(a)
            finished = False
            break
```

It will produce:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2]
[2]
```